# I was trying to install packeges for ns3 but for every command I am getting same error

Tags: 16.04

Error appears in case of installing packages:

`E: The package linux-headers-4.15.0-96 needs to be reinstalled`

but I can't find an archive for it

Comment: How did you install linux-headers-4.15.0-96? linux-headers-4.15.0-96 is not in the default 16.04 repos.

Answer (score 0):

Load into a different working generic kernel and purge the one with broken headers:

```
sudo apt purge *4.15.0-96*
```

Then you will be able to install packages and compile the new one custom kernel if required.

To boot into different kernel, you could use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version).